# SQL is it possible to combine group, count and distinct?

Tags: mysql

I manage a registration system, where people can register for a course, and I have the following query to calculate some statistics:

```
SELECT p.id_country AS id, c.name, COUNT(p.id_country) AS total
                FROM participants p
            LEFT JOIN countries c ON p.id_country = c.id
            WHERE p.id_status NOT IN (3,4,13,14)
            GROUP BY p.id_country
            ORDER BY total DESC
```

this query works fine, it shows me exactly the number of participants per country.
Now it is possible for our system to register for multiple courses, and for every registration a new row will be inserted in the participants table. I know, it's not ideal situation, but unfortunately it's too late to change this right now. If a participant registers for a second (or a third, fourth etc) course, then he uses the same email address. So in the participant table the same email address can be there multiple times.

what I would like to do is change this query, so that it takes into account that every email address can be used only once. the field is just p.email, and I think I should do something with DISTINCT to make this happen. But whatever I try, it either gives me very weird results or an error.

is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to mix distinct and group by in queries. You get the same result doing:

```
select distinct  p.id_country from participants
```

than doing

```
select p.id_country from participants group by p.id_country
```

What you need is to filter out duplicates:

```
SELECT p.id_country AS id, c.name, COUNT(p.id_country) AS total
            FROM participants p
        LEFT JOIN countries c ON p.id_country = c.id
        WHERE p.id_status NOT IN (3,4,13,14)
              and not exists 
           (select email from participants p2 where p1.email=p2.email and p1.id>p2.id)
        GROUP BY p.id_country
        ORDER BY total DESC
```

This will only count emails once, by not counting the newer IDS of account with duplicated emails.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding `UNIQUE` constraint on the table?

```
ALTER TABLE participants ADD CONSTRAINT part_uq UNIQUE (email)
```

Comment: the thing is that the email is not unique, it should absolutely be possible to use the same email more than once

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.id_country AS id, 
    c.name, 
    COUNT(p.id_country) AS total
FROM 
    (select p.mail, max(id_country) as id_country from participants where p.id_status not in (3,4,13,14) group by p.mail) p
    LEFT JOIN countries c ON p.id_country = c.id
GROUP BY 
    p.id_country
ORDER BY 
    total DESC
```

I am using `max(id_country)` for the case where one email adress has more countries. If this cannot happen by design, you can move `id_country` to `group by` clause.

Comment: thanks, I went with Alex' solution, this seems to work as well though :)